# Glitched reviews on Google Play app

Tags: android, mobile

I have an app on Google Play named "Tap n Flap" and I have been getting many great reviews. My issue is that I received a one -star rating from one user and the dev console won't let me view it. I have clicked the filter button and selected one star and this is what I get and it says no reviews match your settings. I do not understand why it will not pop up, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated on dealing with this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 0):

You can't view reviews without a user's comment in Developer Console